# What is the Quadrature rule under these conditions?

Tags: numerical-methods

all
Is there any quadrature rule with error of $O (h^6)$ when using 5 nodal points?

The five nodal points are uniformly distributed.
For instance, [-1,0.5,0,0.5,1] or [a, ....,b]

I am trying to find the one which satisfies those condition.
If so, could you give an idea or an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A closed Newton-Cotes Formula, with 5 points, with $x_i=x_0+ih$ and $i=0(1)4$ gives:

$$
\int_{x_0}^{x_4}f(x)dx= \frac{2h}{45}\left[ 7f(x_0)+32f(x_1)+12f(x_2)+32f(x_3)+7f(x_4) \right]-\frac{8h^7}{945}f^{(6)}(\xi)
$$

for some $\xi\in[x_0,x_4]$, which is $O(h^7)$.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the reply. However, we are finding the one with O(h^6). Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Must it be $O(h^6)$? If $h$ is sufficiently small, then a $O(h^7)$ error is better than a $O(h^6)$ error. 
All Newton-Cotes formulas with an odd number of nodal points (with $n+1$ points, where $n$ is even) will give an error of $O(h^{n+3})$, so it is not possible to have $O(h^6)$